# Find the multiple html tags in a div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to replace my HTML texts that are wrapped by `em` and `u` tags.

so for example:

```
<div id='test'>
This is the test and <em> <u> texts here will need to be replaced </u></em> to a link.
</div>
```

I want to make every word of `'texts here will need to be replaced' linkable`. so in my case it has sever `<a>` tags.

My codes are

```
var texts = $('#test');
        texts.find('em u').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).html();
        $(this).replaceWith("<a href='#' class='link' onclick='return false;'>" + text + "</a>");
    })
```

There are two issues of my codes.
I can't seem to 'find' the texts under `<em><u>` tag. if I change to `find('u')` it works.

2.I want to have 7 a tags for my results so `'texts' 'here' 'will' 'need' 'to' 'be' 'replaced'` will be linkable. My codes only create 1 link for 7 words.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: And to what URL should they link?

Comment: @DavidThomas just # not an actual link.

Comment: Fair enough, though I remain curious as to the *point* of this exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#test u').html(function(){
    var words = $(this).text().split(/\s+/);
    for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i<len; i++){
        if (words[i].length) {
            words[i] = '<a href="#">' + words[i] + '</a>';
        }
    }
    return words.join(' ');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HgDpZ/).

And, if you'd prefer to remove the `u` element, simply use `unwrap()`:

```
$('#test u').html(function(){
    var words = $(this).text().split(/\s+/);
    for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i<len; i++){
        if (words[i].length) {
            words[i] = '<a href="#">' + words[i] + '</a>';
        }
    }
    return words.join(' ');
}).find('a').unwrap();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HgDpZ/1/).

To remove both the `u` and the `em` elements (regardless of which is nested within each) the following works, but it feels messy and, frankly, would benefit vastly from having ordered/properly-structured HTML:

```
$('#test u > em, #test em > u').html(function () {
    var words = $(this).text().split(/\s+/);
    for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (words[i].length) {
            words[i] = '<a href="#">' + words[i] + '</a>';
        }
    }
    return words.join(' ');
}).find('a').unwrap().unwrap();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HgDpZ/2/).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

Comment: Thanks, I have a follow up question. What if the html markup has <em><u> and <u><em> mixed. How do I replace them all? +1

Comment: That depends on what you want to *do*, are you looking to remove *just* the `u`? Or both the `em` *and* the `u`?

Comment: I want to remove both em and u

Answer (score 1):

```
var texts = $('#test');

texts.find('em u').each(function () {
    var words = $(this).html().split(' ');
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var link = words[i]; // Change this to whatever
        output += '<a href="' + link + '" class="link" onclick="return false;">' + words[i] + '</a> ';
    }
    $(this).html(output);
});
```

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/xyx4f/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions

```
$('#test em u').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this); 
    var html = $this.html().replace(/\s?(\w+)\s?/g, "<a href='#'>$1</a>");
    $this.html(html);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/assR6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    var texts = $('#test');
    texts.find('em > u').html(function(idx, html){
        return html.replace(/(\w+)/g, '<a href="#" class="link" onclick="return false;">$1</a>')
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RYcBT/)